# Can I check which files in the Git repository was over a certain size even when the files were deleted?

Tags: git

While doing a `git clone`, I saw that some particular objects was taking some time to download, and it seemed like it was 100MB or more.

But say, if I can't find such big file in the current working directory, does that mean it is in the repo object store, but it was deleted?  If that's the case, is there a way to find all files in the repo history for files that was over 100MB in size?

Comment: [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) may be able to help you.